# I am unable to access tomcat server(localhost), not even getting access of mysql

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

Yesterday i was building the website on wordpress and its showing directly on localhost. but when i was accessing my java project from tomcat server then i could not open tomcat server having port no. 3306. also  i was unable to access  mysql query browser. It showing an error like could not connect to specific access.

Comment: your local server is tomcat and port default port number is 8080 go through some tutorials

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand that `8080` is the default port of Tomcat and `3306` is the default port of mysql. Then perform some basic trouble shooting steps like,

- Check the port number in your server.xml file (for tomcat). You might have changed it earlier.
- Check that your port is not occupied by any other processes etc.